# Django `loaddata` pretty way to load same objects with different pk (id)

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I use `loaddata` to load my fixtures ([Django doc.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#loaddata))

For example i have this `example.json`:

```
[
 {
   "model": "foo.bar",
   "pk": 1,
   "fields": {
     "name": "dmytryi"
   }
 },
  {
   "model": "foo.bar",
   "pk": 2,
   "fields": {
     "name": "dmytryi"
   }
 },
 ... (repeat it until pk is not 10 with increasing pk by one)
 {
   "model": "foo.bar",
   "pk": 10,
   "fields": {
     "name": "dmytryi"
   }
 },
]
```

How you see, I have 10 same objects (same name for same model), but with different `pk` value. After `loaddata` I will see in my database 10 objects. It is OK.

Give a hint how to reduce the code, but leave the same result, if it exists. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

```
base =  {
   "model": "foo.bar",
   "fields": {
     "name": "dmytryi"
   }
}

data = [{**base, **{'pk': id}} for id in range(1, 11)]
```

This will unpack the `base` dictionary and the `{'pk': id}` dictionary into a new dictionary. The output looks like this:

```
[{'fields': {'name': 'dmytryi'}, 'model': 'foo.bar', 'pk': 0},
 {'fields': {'name': 'dmytryi'}, 'model': 'foo.bar', 'pk': 1},
 {'fields': {'name': 'dmytryi'}, 'model': 'foo.bar', 'pk': 2},
 {'fields': {'name': 'dmytryi'}, 'model': 'foo.bar', 'pk': 3},
 {'fields': {'name': 'dmytryi'}, 'model': 'foo.bar', 'pk': 4},
 {'fields': {'name': 'dmytryi'}, 'model': 'foo.bar', 'pk': 5},
 {'fields': {'name': 'dmytryi'}, 'model': 'foo.bar', 'pk': 6},
 {'fields': {'name': 'dmytryi'}, 'model': 'foo.bar', 'pk': 7},
 {'fields': {'name': 'dmytryi'}, 'model': 'foo.bar', 'pk': 8},
 {'fields': {'name': 'dmytryi'}, 'model': 'foo.bar', 'pk': 9}]
```

You could make it even shorter like this:

```
[{**{'fields': {'name': 'dmytryi'}, 'model': 'foo.bar',}, **{'pk': i}} for i in range(1, 11)]
```

but I think that's worse.